# Spring Boot JUnit Jackson Cannot Deserialize All Fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, jackson

I have a test case that cannot pass:

```
ContactDTO contactDTO = generateContactDTO();

HttpEntity<ContactDTO> request = new HttpEntity<>(contactDTO, headers);

ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(generateBaseUrl() + "/contacts", HttpMethod.POST, request, Response.class);
assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
```

Here is my ContactDTO class:

```
public class ContactDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 100)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    ContactDTO(@JsonProperty("firstName") @NotNull @Size(min = 2, max = 100) String firstName,
           @JsonProperty("lastName") @NotNull @Size(min = 2, max = 100) String lastName,
           @JsonProperty("email") @NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 50) String email,
           @JsonProperty("phoneNumber") @NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 50) String phoneNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    private void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    private void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Response<String>> createContact(@Validated @RequestBody ContactDTO contactDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        LOG.debug("Contact could not validated: {} and won't be created" +
                " Validation error is as follows: {}", contactDTO, bindingResult);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new Response<>(Error.CONTACT_VALIDATION));
    }
    ...
}
```

When I debug it, I see that all fields are populated at contactDTO before it's been send to controller. However, at controller, only e-mail field is populated and it results with HTTP Bad Request.

**PS:** I use Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: Can you show the code of the controller please ?

Comment: Please show your generateContactDTO code as well.

Comment: Hi Kamaci, Please create JSON string of ContactDTO and verify that correct JSON has been created also show the reason for bad request it could be you have not set application type in header

Comment: I've added my controller code. Binding result has errors when I debug it. generateContactDTO() runs well because it populates object's fields. When I test it via Postman I don't get any errors.

Comment: @VishalPawar I've created the json string from the object and there is only email written at there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no public accessors, Jackson could not serialize my DTO. So, I've added this at top of my DTO object:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
```